# If memory can be saved by using static methods, why aren't all methods declared as static (instead of using instance methods)?

Tags: java

In Java, a static method is used to save memory because there is no need to create an object to call static methods. And we need to create an object when we have to call instance methods; so whenever we create an object it takes memory. We know that, in any project, maximum methods are non-static.

Why then do we not declare all methods as static, instead of having instance methods be the norm, in order to save memory in a project?

Comment: This seems to be instead asking why we use objects.

Comment: Because we want a higher level of Abstraction, that object oriented programming provides...

Comment: Why do we use OOP instead of Plain Old Basic!

Comment: If you don't need an instance of the containing class to run the method, then by all means make it static. But how would you, say, have a List without an instance of a List? It's merely convenient to be able to call `list.add(something)` rather than `List.add(list, something)`; in both cases, you have an instance of the list.

Comment: The premise of the question is faulty: static methods are not used to save memory. They are used to facilitate better OOD.

Comment: *"In java static method is used to save memory..."* I think I can honestly say I've never created a static method in order to save memory. That's in ~13 years of active Java programming spread over a 25-year period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some methods — probably most — need information in order to do their work. You have to store that information *somewhere*.

If all of your methods are static, that doesn't magically make the need for that information go away. And if you need the information, you need to store it, so you can pass it into the static method so the method can do its work. So there's no memory savings achieved by using only static methods: You're going to store that information *somewhere*.

In Java's style of object-oriented programming (and many but not all others), you store that information *with* (conceptually) the functions that operate on it (instance methods): An object.

For methods that *don't* need information, or that reasonably should receive all of the information they operate on via parameters, we use static methods.

Comment: Just to elaborate: non-static methods are not stored *with* the data. Only one copy of those methods exists in memory no matter how many instances you make.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus - Hence "conceptually." :-)